# AWS Cloudwatch Dashboards: How to add dashboard from one account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I want to add dashboards(including the metrics) in aws account A to my aws account B in AWS CloudWatch, is it possible to do that? In order to do that, what kind of permission should I have to add dashboards from account A?

Thank you.

Comment: please review and post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. also your question seems like it could be solved by a google search

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch now supports cross account cross region dashboards. See the documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html#enable-cross-account-cross-Region

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is now a supported feature in CloudWatch Console - see the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html)

This is not something supported by CloudWatch today, but you could use CloudWatch GetMetricWidgetImage API to basically snapshot the data, put the graph image in a shared s3 bucket and display that instead.
See an example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/reduce-time-to-resolution-with-amazon-cloudwatch-snapshot-graphs-and-alerts/)